# Partition BigQuery by String

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partitioning

I have dataset that I am trying to create a table for in BQ and I would like to partition it by a field "yearmonth" that looks like "Mar1998". There are 80 of these months and they break up my 660M row dataset into relatively even chunks, but BQ won't let me partition by "yearmonth" because it is a string. Is there a way that I can parse the string into a date and partition on that? Would creating a new column and using a function to convert "Mar1998" to an integer and then partitioning using a range work?

Comment: Just convert it to the first day of the month and partition by date.  Using a string for partitioning is a little silly, because `>` and `<` don't even work sensibly on the value.

Answer (score 3):

You are in right direction ...

You can use `PARSE_DATE('%B%Y', yearmonth)` to create new column of DATE type and partition by that new column

In case of "Mar1998" - this new DATE field will be "1998-03-01"